# Find the max between two cells but not including the cells

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, max

I am a beginner in VBA and have been using the loop extensively to automate some work on a data set. I have a set of dates and between these dates are empty cells. I have filled in the empty cells with TRUE values and now want to find the maximum between two sequential TRUE values but obviously not including these cells, then i want to route through my entire data set with this.

My problem is i cannot seem to find a way to create a macro that finds the correct upper and lower bound and then find the max between this which then returns the results in a different column with one under the other

[image]

For example i want to take the data between the second and third TRUE, find the maximum value and then paste this maximum into say D2. Then i want to go to the third and fourth True and do the same. So in the end i should have a column of max dates

The max function that excel draws up on the record macro feature references the upper and lower bounds with regards to the position you want to paste the max value, however as the amount of cells changes between the bounds I cannot make a list of max values - some will fall short other, will go beyond.

My though was to develop a macro that finds the first TRUE, looks for the next TRUE and then works out the max between, but not including, these two. Then i would Range("D1").value = max("first true:second true") to deposit y value. Going on to the next loop, it would find the third TRUE and would out the max between the second and third, again not including these two cells, and Range("D2").value = max("second true:third true").

I just don't know how to make the max function work like this. I also don't know how to route through the list of TRUEs so that I am always in the right place

Comment: You can take a look at [Range.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) method. There's a demo code.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:

- Read the range into a VBA Array

  - If this link is still good, this excellent discussion by the late Chip Pearson on [Arrays and Ranges in VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx) is helpful.
- loop through the range and collect the maximum date after each instance of `TRUE` into a `Dictionary` object (a handy storage collection).
- Go through the Dictionary to output the results.
- The function can be built to output either a vertical or horizontal array

  - see the notes about this.
- Depending on your version of Excel, it may just output the values as an array, or you may have to either enter it in a range as an array function, or use the INDEX function to access each element.
- You could also turn this into a macro that would output the results in a predetermined range, but, of course, at the expense of easily making it dynamic.

```
Option Explicit
Function maxDateList(rg As Range)
    Dim Arr As Variant
    Dim D As Object
    Dim I As Long
    Dim KEY As Long
    Dim V As Variant

'read range into vba array for speedy processing:
'This is always a 2D array
Arr = rg

'loop through the range, saving the max date into
'our dictionary object, and changing dictionary
'entries on each instance of TRUE

Set D = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For I = 1 To UBound(Arr)
    If Arr(I, 1) = True Then KEY = I
    If IsDate(Arr(I, 1)) Then
        If Not D.Exists(KEY) Then
            D.Add KEY:=KEY, Item:=Arr(I, 1)
        Else
            If Arr(I, 1) > D(KEY) Then D(KEY) = Arr(I, 1)
        End If
    End If
Next I

'Output the results as an array
'use 2d array for vertical output
'    1d array for horizontal output
I = 0
ReDim Arr(1 To D.Count, 1 To 1)
For Each V In D
    I = I + 1
    Arr(I, 1) = D(V)
Next V

'output the results
maxDateList = Arr

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: I have been trying to follow this code but when i implement it into my sub it only populates the first max.

My code to use the function is as follows


Dim rg As Range,
Set rg = Range("B1:B33"),

Range("E1").Value = maxDateList(rg), 

This is my first time using a function so i am aware that my syntax maybe all off!

Comment: @Zain You need to read the link I posted about Ranges and Arrays in VBA.  He writes that when transferring an array from VBA to the worksheet, the target range needs to be the same size and dimensions as the array. So something like `v = maxDateList(rg): Range("E1").Resize(RowSize:=ubound(v,1)).Value = v` should work.  Lots of other useful information at that link, also.